# Django query with __range and F

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am trying to write a query that filters based on particular date. Let say i have three data in the db

```
target_date = 28th of october
today = 23rd of october

data one
publish_date = 26th of october

data two
publish_date = 24th of october

data three
publish_date = target_date   # 28th of october
```

My query needs to fetch all data that is three or less days before the target date. since target date is 28th of october, any data within the range of 26th, 27th and 28th (target date) should be fetched.

query

```
MyModel.objects.filter(
    publish_date__range=[F('publish_date'),  F('publish_date') - timedelta(days=3)]
)
```

The target_date vary based on the row data.
I am getting unexpected result.

Answer (score 0):

first: "I am getting unexpected result." bad way to understand your problem

second: any way you will have problem in filter because you added min date after max date.

third: your where clause in sql will looks like:

```
WHERE "publish_date" BETWEEN F(publish_date) AND F(publish_date)  - DurationValue(3 days, 0:00:00)
```

it applied for each row, so you will get empty query set

at last as i can see you can try simple way:

```
target_date = MyModel.objects.filter(HERE_YOUR_RULE).first().publish_date
from_date = target_date - timedelta(days=3)
MyModel.objects.filter(publish_date__range=[from_date, target_date])
```

don't forget to change `HERE_YOUR_RULE`, hope it help.

Comment: this won't work for me because it will only use the first data as reference, the target_date can vary based on the data row. Probably i did not explain well

Answer (score 0):

Try this filter:

```
reference_date = MyModel.objects \ 
    .filter(user=some_user_receiving_email) \
    .order_by('-is_published')[0].is_published

queryset_to_include_in_email = MyModel.objects.filter(
    publish_date__gte=reference_date - timedelta(days=3), 
    publish_date__lte=reference_date
)
```

Comment: the target_date can vary based on the row, can you explain more about the reference_date? Thanks

Comment: Just so that I understand, is there a `target_date` field in your table in addition to a `publish_date` field?

Comment: there is no target_date, i only have publish_date, i want to fetch all data that will be published 3 days before publish_date and send emails to the user. So the publish_date differs based on what the user inputs

Comment: How do we know when the object is published? Do you have any other datefield to show that?

Comment: Yeah, i have it `is_published`

Comment: How do we know when it was actually published? Do you have any other datefield other than the 'published_date' ? Only then I think we would know whether it was published before the actual date or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
MyModel.objects.
        filter(publish_date__range=
            [F('publish_date'),  F('publish_date') + timedelta(days=3)])
```

Which will fetch all the objects whose published_date in range between the published date and three days after it was published.